# Include VueJS Plugin without Javascript Package Manager

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

How can I use VueJS plugins if I don't use any Javascript Package Managers (NodeJS, NPM)?

I'm building an app made from a Bootstrap template and Server Side framework in Coldfusion (CFWheels).

I wanted to use some of VueJS's functionality such as two-way data-binding, easier integration of animation using animate.css, etc. I included it via

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

However, I can't use NPM as the app will be continually be improved and maintained in production.

I wanted to use some VueJS plugin such as VueJS typeahead.

When I include the script, and try the documentation, there are errors in the Javascript like being unable to import, export module, require. I think these are modern Javascript coding style that are not recognized in my setup because I didn't use the NPM and require those polyfills.

Is there a way that I can make those VueJS plugins work? Or if I can just include the polyfills needed and proceed with the plugin documentations so the browser will understand those new JS terms without using NPM or other Javascript Package Manager.

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to progress much with modern tools (JavaScript frameworks in particular), then you need to learn how to use not only a package manager but also an appropriate build system. The errors you're seeing are related to the lack of a build system which would resolve those `import` and `export` statements. With something like Vue as well, components are going to be often distributed in a format that absolutely requires a build step specific to the format of those components (e.g. Vue has single file components which include JavaScript, HTML and CSS all in the one .vue file).

Comment: I wanted to progress, but in our setup I cannot do it. One is because, I cannot upload a minified version of the application in production. The source code should be as is to what is in the production. Another one is that I try to fetch anything from the internet to the production server using NPM, it just doesn't work. Only the production server has Adobe Coldfusion installed, so basically I don't have any development server other than the server itself. I can create a copy of my app, but it still will be tested in the production server.

Comment: If there is no way to lift that constraint then you're simply unable to properly leverage the Vue ecosystem :-( Many plugins do come with a compiled file for the browser to load but many don't - for example, [this is what I distribute](https://github.com/MartyWallace/vue-keyboard/blob/master/src/keyboard.vue) in one of my Vue components.